# How to mount a grape swagger into mountable engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, grape-api

I am developing a rails api with grape and I am putting the functionality into a mountable engine.

In the engine routes I mount the API:

```
  mount API => '/'
```

In the test_app I am mounting the engine:

```
mount XBackend::Engine => "/"
```

The specs are passing when they access the api endpoints.

These are the relevant routes listed by rake routes:

```
   api_swagger GET      /api/swagger(.:format)                 swagger#index
Routes for XBackend::Engine:
   api      /           API
```

Despite all this I can't access the /api/swagger.

It throws me this exception:

```
Missing template layouts/swagger with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/boti/Rails/clients/projectlounge/encore_backend/spec/test_app/app/views" * "/Users/boti/Rails/clients/projectlounge/encore_backend/app/views" * "/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@encore_backend/gems/grape-swagger-ui-0.0.4/app/views" * "/Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@encore_backend/gems/devise-3.3.0/app/views"
```

Comment: it looks like you don't have `swagger` layout, maybe just specify some layout manualy like: `layout :application` in your controller

Comment: That was the answer, thank you